# How to sync photo Dropbox?

Tags: android, api, synchronization, dropbox

I'm using the Dropbox API for Android for the first time and I'm having some troubles, I call the `Sync` when the camera result (`onActivityResult`) and the code:

```
public void dropSync (File file) {
    if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
        try {
            photo = dbxFs.create(new DbxPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        } catch (InvalidPathException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DbxException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            photo.writeFromExistingFile(file, false);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        DbxFileStatus status = null;
        try {
            status = photo.getSyncStatus();
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!status.isCached) {
            photo.addListener(new DbxFile.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onFileChange(DbxFile file) {
                        try {
                            if (file.getSyncStatus().isCached) {
                              file.update();
                              // deal with the new value
                              Log.e("TAG", "*** VALUE *** " + file.readString());
                            }
                        } catch (DbxException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            });
            // Check if testFile.getSyncStatus() is ready already to ensure nothing
            // was missed while adding the listener
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is when my photo arrives on Dropbox it has 0 bytes. And the File comes from here:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          photoUri = null;
          if (data == null) {
            // A known bug here! The image should have saved in fileUri
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            photoUri = fileUri;
          } else {
            photoUri = data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully in: " + data.getData(), 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          // showPhoto(photoUri);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Callout for image capture failed!", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }

      dropSync(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath));
}
```

Comment: Does `photo.writeFromExistingFile` succeed? Or do you catch an exception there?

Comment: Also, I don't see where you're catching the potential `DbxException` from `writeFromExistingFile`. Is that caught somewhere else?

Comment: Also, you should probably call `close()` on the `DbxFile` once you've written to it.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the time, I put to print the DbxException and I get this: "cannot read file: /.../....jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already read the file, so its position is at the end of the file instead of the beginning.

Comment: Hi, I put on my original post. Thanks.